# How to compare different positions of digits of two integers?

Tags: java

I am creating a simple number game in Java.

Simply, the game is all about guessing numbers.

However, I want to add a function to check if the numbers are correct or not.

For example:

```
int targetNumber = 1743;
int userGuess = 1564;
```

Now, since the digit `1` in `userGuess` belongs in the accurate position with `targetNumber`, it would print out the letter `A`.

The digits `5` and `6` in `userGuess` doesn't belong anywhere in `targetNumber`, it would print out the letter `I` (Stands for Inaccurate).

However, the digit `4` does belong in `targetNumber` but not it its ACCURATE position. In this case, it would print out the letter `S` (Stands for Semi-Accurate).

I'm strugging checking semi-accurate digits, I have already separated the digits from both `userGuess` and `targetNumber`, and stored them in two arrays like this:

```
int[] targetNumber = new int[4];
targetNumber[0] = 1;
targetNumber[1] = 7;
targetNumber[2] = 4;
targetNumber[3] = 3;

int[] userGuess = new int[4];
userGuess[0] = 1;
userGuess[1] = 5;
userGuess[2] = 6;
userGuess[3] = 4;
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: With some modification, this wouldn't be a bad Code Golf challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest doing it without storing the digits individually as a list. First convert both to String. Then, run a loop to iterate over each character. If the characters at the current index of both strings are the same, display "A". Else, check - if the character at all exists in `targetNumber`; if it does, display "S", else display "I".

```
public static void function(int targetNumber, int userGuess){
    String a = Integer.toString(targetNumber), 
           b = Integer.toString(userGuess);
    for(int i=0 ; i<4; i++){
        if(a.charAt(i) == b.charAt(i))
            System.out.print("A");
        else{
            if(a.indexOf(b.charAt(i)) == -1)
                System.out.print("I");
            else
                System.out.print("S");
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, since your targetNumber is 1743 and userGuess is 1564, you should call

```
function(1743, 1564);
```

which will display the output as

```
AIIS
```

Comment: At first I didn't know what you meant, but this is WAY better than storing each digits in a list, thank you :)

Answer (score 6):

If you store them in an `ArrayList<Integer> numbers`, then you could simply call `numbers.contains(yourInt)`. Otherwise you could start with a `boolean` and iterate through the list setting it to `true` and `breaking` if you ever find it.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a very optimal solution. But you can do something like this:

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int targetNumber = 1743;
        int userGuess = 1564;
        String target = "" + targetNumber;
        String guess = "" + userGuess;

        for (int i = 0; i < guess.length(); i++) {
            char ch = guess.charAt(i);
            int j = target.indexOf(ch);
            if (j == -1) {
                System.out.println("I");
            } else if (j == i) {
                System.out.println("A");
            } else {
                System.out.println("S");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int[] targetNum = {1, 7, 4, 3};
    int[] userGuess = {1, 5, 6, 4};

    List<Integer> targetList = IntStream.of(targetNum).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> guessList = IntStream.of(userGuess).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());


    for (Integer currentGuess : guessList) {
        if(targetList.contains(currentGuess)) {
            int targetIndex = targetList.indexOf(currentGuess);
            int guessIndex = guessList.indexOf(currentGuess);

            if(targetIndex == guessIndex) {
                System.out.println("A");
            } else {
                System.out.println("S");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("I");
        }
    }
```